# StringEnumeration (Enumeration in General)

Tags: java, enumeration

Ok so the goal of the class is to override the two methods inside of the Enumeration object class. I believe my `hasNextElement()` method should work, any pointers on that would be appreciated. I, however, am having troubles with the `nextElement()` method. Excuse the improper commenting throught the class but the goal of `nextElement()` is to return one character at a time. I figured its just a simple loop but netBeans keeps giving me incompatible dataTypes, which makes sense because its a String method not a Char method. So I change it to char and I get

```
nextElement() in StringEnumeration cannot implement nextElement() in Enumeration return type char is not compatible with String where E is a type-variable:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Do remember I am a beginner programmer so I may have done something wrong that is easily fixable.

```
public class StringEnumeration implements Enumeration<String> {

    public String value;

    public StringEnumeration(String initialValue) throws InvalidStringException {
        if (initialValue == null || initialValue.length() == 0) {
            throw new InvalidStringException("initialValue is either null or 0");
        }

        this.value = initialValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        return value.length() != 0 || value != null;
    }

    @Override
    public String nextElement() {
        StringBuffer test = new StringBuffer(value);
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
            return test.charAt(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop in next element always return the first character of the string. That's not what you want. So you need to change to keep int i as a variable inside your enumeration. Also, if nextElement returns a Character, then you implement Enumeration<Character>, not String.

Comment: Are you using `java.util.Enumeration`? It's a pretty old API to be using in 2015 when you have `Iterator` available.

Comment: @ChetanKinger: well it could have been useful to allow both and make `Iterator<T>` an extension of `Enumeration<T>`. Now one has no means to know at compile time whether an item can be removed.

Comment: @CommuSoft Good point. Even though one can `throw` an exception if `remove` is called, it's not as good as not providing an option to call `remove` at compile time itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
//know acess modifiers well...
private String value;

private Integer currentPosition;

public StringEnumeration(String initialValue) throws InvalidStringException {
    if (initialValue == null || initialValue.length() == 0) {
        throw new InvalidStringException("initialValue is either null or 0");
    }

    this.value = initialValue;
} 

//you would return false when the list is empty OR the current position is
//past the end of the string
@Override
public boolean hasMoreElements() {
    return value.length() != 0 || currentPosition < value.length();
}

//you would return the character at the current position
@Override
public char nextElement() {
    return value.charAt(currentPosition++);

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you better use `currentPosition < value.length()`. Say you call `nextElement()` twice in `try`-environments, then the cursor can have been moved over the length. In general `<` is safer than `==`...

Comment: This was the code that did it. Thanks for the help I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to keep the index you're at as a variable in the enumeration:

```
// we return characters 
public class StringEnumeration implements Enumeration<Character> {
    // the value
    private String value;
    // current index
    private int idx=0;

    public StringEnumeration(String initialValue) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (initialValue == null || initialValue.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("initialValue is either null or 0");
        }

        this.value = initialValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        // can we still read
        return idx<value.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Character nextElement() {
        // get current char and increment index
        return value.charAt(idx++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should a string with `.length` `0` not be acceptable? A collection containing no elements can be enumerated as well.

Comment: That was in the original code, I suppose the poster had his reasons, but of course you're right.

Comment: think I've found the reason: in case the string has no element, the `for`-loop will not be executed and thus nothing will be returned. But the compiler has probably no intelligence to understand this. The compiler should error on the fact it is possible nothing is returned.

Comment: Sorry? My code works fine if your remove the check for the empty string. If value.length()==0, then idx<value.length() is always false,so hasMoreElements() always return false.

Comment: indeed. I was referring to the OP's code: since he/she implemented a `for` loop  in the `nextElement` a compiler has to be conservative and will reason it is possible the loop is never executed. That is probably the reason the OP added a "larger than zero" constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you intend to implement is an [`Iterator<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) over the characters of a given string:

```
public class StringEnumeration implements Iterator<Character> {

    private final String value;
    private int index = 0;

    public StringEnumeration(String initialValue) {
        if(initialValue == null) {
            this.value = "";
        } else {
            this.value = initialValue;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < value.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Character next() {
        try {
            return test.charAt(this.index);
        } finally {
            this.index++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        //can be done. Necessary?
    }

}
```

(You can use an [`Enumeration<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) by simply replacing `Iterator<Character>` with `Enumeration<Character>`; and `hasNext` and `next` with `hasMoreElements` and `nextElement` and remove the `remove` method.

This iterator considers that the `null` String and the empty string `""` contain both zero characters.

An iterator needs to store a state in the iteration process: the `index` of the character to enumerate. Initially the `index` is set to `0`. After each item, the index is incremented.

Furthermore the test is simply whether the value has already reached the end of the `String`.

The main problem with your code is the following:

```
@Override
public String nextElement() {
    StringBuffer test = new StringBuffer(value);
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        return test.charAt(i);
    }

}
```

You use a `for`-loop but with a return statement. If you thus ask for the `nextElement` Java will start iterating and immediately `return` the first character. Furthermore this probably won't compile since the Java compiler can't figureout `test` has at least one element and thus it is possible that the `for` loop is never executed.

## Other advice

Please always make fields `private`. By making fields public, a class can no longer guarantee the consistency of its state.

Furthermore `Iterator` is a *modern* version of `Enumeration` (although there is some discussion about this).

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation has several problems.

First, in `Enumeration<E>` the `E` is not the type the enumeration is working on. It's the type that the `nextElement()` method is supposed to return. So an `Enumeration<String>` has a `nextElement()` method that returns `String`. But your implementation returns the result of `charAt()` - a method that returns the primitive `char`, not a `String`! You either have to return some sort of string (maybe a single-char string like `"m"`) or a `Character` (because you can't make `E` a primitive type like `char`).

---

The next problem is that your `hasNextElement()` method is not actually correct. An `Enumeration` is intended to give you one *element* (character, in your case) of the data at a time, and each time you call `nextElement()` it moves ahead towards the end of the data. so `hasNextElement()` has to return `true` based on whether or not there is still another element to go through. Your implementation, however, will always return true for the same string. It will not give an indication when to stop calling `nextElement()`.

---

Last, your `nextElement()` somehow thinks that it's going to return all the elements at the same time. This cannot work. An `Enumeration` can only give one element each time you call `nextElement()`. So using a loop inside it makes no sense. The proper way to do this is to keep state inside the `Enumeration` object, say a variable named `next`, that indicates where the next element is. Each time the caller calls `nextElement()`, you take that element, advance `next`, and return the element. One element at a time, no loops. The actual loop will be created by whoever is using the `Enumeration`, not by the `Enumeration` itself.

It is also this `next` field (or whatever you want to call it) that can help you to create a proper `hasMoreElements()` method. If the `next` reaches beyond the end of the string, `hasMoreElements()` has to return false, and `nextElement()` has to throw `NoSuchElementException`.